# How do I move the dock in GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome, unity-dash, dock

10 and I'm just trying to get it the way I want it. To this end I have decided to use the gome-session-manager instead of Ubuntu. I am currently using the dock shell extension but it is in a really awkward place in my opinion and I can't seem to move it. Can it be moved and if so how ? Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what *dock* you are talking about please?

Comment: And what is "10 and I'm ..."? Did you leave something out? Please edit your question.

Comment: Yeah it seems to have cut out the first few lines of my question, its ok though I now have the answer, I found it by searching for dock in the tags section, should have done that first really lol